# SI - ppm/ degree celsius

Tags: siunitx

How can I write `ppm/°C` in latex using SI units?

I tried this: `\SI{}{\ppm / \degree \celsius}` and it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

As reminded by @leandriis in his commentary to have only the unit without the measurement, it is enough to use the same command, but in lowercase letters, here `\si` instead of `\SI`.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\si{ppm \per \celsius} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: To just get the unit (without a number), you might want to use `\si{ppm \per \celsius} ` instead of `\SI{}...`.